# How to get values ​from multiple elements with the same class-name using jquery

Tags: jquery

I print out a table with a foreach loop using and each row will have a form with some hidden input and a submit buttons, like this

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item['name'] ?>" class="get_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item['email'] ?>" class="get_email">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item['address'] ?>" class="get_address">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item['birthday'] ?>" class="get_birthday">
    <button type="submit" class="Add">Add</button>
</form>
```

What I want to ask here is how to get the value in a row when I hit the submit button in that row. I used `$('.classname').val()` and the only result I got was the value of the first row in the table.

Comment: Please also post your jquery code.

Comment: @justDan yeah i used $('.classname').val() - but it only return value of the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using `val()`, which works as intended:

`Get the current value of the first element....`

If you loop through your elements using `.each()`, you can retrieve the values of all elements like this:

```
$("input[type=hidden]").each(function() {
 console.log($(this).val())
}
```

No offense, but this question is quite trivial and requires only some basic jQuery knowledge or how to search in the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function). Instead of heading directly to your solution, I would recommend, that you take a jQuery introduction like this to understand how to traverse the DOM and extract data using jQuery:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to clearly understand what you're trying to achieve, but a way to get all values in a row would be that:

```js
var row = {};
$('input[type=hidden]').each(function () {
  row[$(this).attr('class')] = $(this).val();
});
console.log(row);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item['name'] ?>" class="get_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item['email'] ?>" class="get_email">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item['address'] ?>" class="get_address">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item['birthday'] ?>" class="get_birthday">
    <button type="submit" class="Add">Add</button>
</form>
```